# Разделение проектов на github

Tags: git, github

Возможно ли как-либо разделить проекты на своем аккаунте на github. Т.е. есть, на пример, есть несколько проектов под ios, есть несколько под android и нужно их логически разделить(как по папкам)

Comment: Эм, ну так создайте несколько репозиториев и всё, в чём проблема? Или вы ещё репозитории по папкам распихать хотите?

Comment: Да, репозитории

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: есть github организации, команды (доступ регулировать), метки (topics). Можно поиском для навигации пользоваться.

Comment: Оу, у вас много реп ;)